# Sqlite error: illegal first argument to matchinfo

Tags: sqlite

I've been struggling with this for quite some time and have to throw in the towel. Using SQLite with Tcl:

```
set _query [sq_handle eval {SELECT matchinfo(column7) FROM myftstable WHERE column7 MATCH 'raindrops keep falling in my hat';}]
puts $_query
```

I keep getting this: error: illegal first argument to matchinfo

I only have the problem with matchinfo, which I need. Ordinary SELECT queries work fine.

I googled, but couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of the [matchinfo() function](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#matchinfo) must be the [special hidden column](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#hiddencol):

```
SELECT matchinfo(myftstable) FROM myftstable WHERE ...
```

Comment: "Every FTS table has a hidden column with the same name as the table itself."

I guess I was reading it as "as the column itself". Thank you.